# How do I select a the closest POI from coordinates in googlemaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a weird problem. I'm making an android app with notifications that lead to google maps.

When going to google maps from the notification I want to select the closest Zara (for example) to the coordinates.

```
    lat = 51.513540;
    longitude = -0.155107;
    fullName = "Zara";
    zoom = 21;


String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:" + lat + "," + longitude + "?z="+ zoom + "&q=" + fullName );
```

When google maps fires up it shows the map zoomed into the proper zoom level and the right coordinates but then it zooms out and shows all the Zaras around london.

There is a zara at that coordinate. I want it to select that specific zara.

Any way I can write this "geo" uri to make it do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in-case anyone is wondering, I kind of found the answer to my question.

If you have a google developer console account available you can go ahead and enable an API called "[Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en_US#ReverseGeocoding)".

Its main purpose is to take place names and turn them into latitudes and longitudes, but it has a neat little trick in that it also contains the functionality to reverse-geocode. Meaning that it will take a latitude and longitude and get the corresponding place. Perfect solution for my question. Thanks Goog!

EDIT: I just tried it with the coordinates in my question, it doesn't get me the result I want, although still an interesting tool.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we can't set radius where to show places from point. 
But you can try this URI

```
geo:0,0?q=latitude,longitude(label)
```

In your case it will be

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=" + lat + "," + longitude +"(" +fullName+ ")");
```

Map will be opened at specific location. Search field and title will be as coordinates, but at the bottom we can see "Labelled as Zara"

Comment: Yeah that's what I settled with at the end. Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: @user2664050 if this answer solves your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @antonio It doesn't really answer my question. It is the second best solution so far.

Comment: @user2664050 ok, it's up to you. Your own answer provides a solution that could be useful for others, that's why I upvoted it :)

Comment: @antonio thank you. Even my answer doesn't actually answer the question completely. As soon as I, or anyone else, finds the right exact solution I'll change the answer accordingly.